# Symfony 3.4 - I have issue using knp-paginator-bundle

Tags: symfony-3.4

I have the following controller

```
/**
*
* @Route("/searchname" , name="search_student_name")
*
*/
public function SearchStudentName(Request $request, SessionInterface $sessionName)
{
    $params = $request->request->all();
    $SName = $params['txtSearchName'];

    if (isset($SName)){
        $sessionName->set('SName', $SName);
    }

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $query = $em->createQuery("SELECT s FROM AppBundle:Student s WHERE s.name LIKE :Name ORDER BY s.name");
    $query->setParameter('Name', '%'.$sessionName->get('SName').'%');

    $students = $query->getArrayResult();
    
    $paginator = $this->get('knp_paginator');
    $result = $paginator->paginate(
      $students,
      $request->query->get('page', 1)/*page number*/,
      50/*limit per page*/
    );

    return $this->render('student/index.html.twig', array(
        'students' => $result,
    ));
}
```

The first page was displayed correctly.
But When I am trying to go to other page

```
app_dev.php/student/searchname?page=2
```

I have the following error:

> NotFoundHttpException
>
> HTTP 404 Not Found
>
> AppBundle\Entity\Student object not found by the @ParamConverter annotation.

I have the indexAction which works fine for any page:

> the only difference is $students = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Student')->findAll();
>
> and the use of session to save the name

```
/**
 * Lists all student entities.
 *
 * @Route("/", name="student_index")
 * @Method("GET")
 */
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $students = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Student')->findAll();

    /**
    * @var $paginator \Knp\Component\Pager\Paginator
    */
    $paginator = $this->get('knp_paginator');
    $result = $paginator->paginate(
      $students,
      $request->query->get('page', 1)/*page number*/,
      50/*limit per page*/
    );

    return $this->render('student/index.html.twig', array(
        'students' => $result,
    ));
}
```

Can someone help me how to solve this issue?

[Session value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A322C.png)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe $sessionName->get('SName') is empty or null ?, you can try put a default value for the session like this:

```
$sessionName->get('SName', 'something default');
```

Comment: the session is not empty

Comment: I added the session value (image) in the question

Comment: what happens i you change $students = $query->getArrayResult(); to  $students = $query->getResult(); ?

Comment: Same thing. The first page works and the other pages don't